# Tibco Spotfire SDK : How to get a list of Cross table names in a dxp file

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I am creating a Spotfire extension that will need to get a list of cross table plot in a dxp file, showing the cross table name in a combo box for users to pick.

Been searching and reading the SDK documentation, but really don't know how to start. Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a away to do it after google through the documents

```
        List<Visual> crosstable = new List<Visual>();
        PageCollection pageList = myApp.Document.Pages;
        foreach (Page page in pageList)
        {
            VisualCollection visualList = page.Visuals;
            foreach (Visual visual in visualList)
            {
                if (visual.TypeId.Name.Contains("CrossTable"))
                {
                    crosstable.Add(visual);
                }
            }
        }
```